# Что вызывать первым: SetWindowPos или ShowWindow?

Tags: c, winapi

В коде на Си мне надо показать окно в первый раз, для этого я вызываю `SetWindowPos` и `ShowWindow`, окно появляется, вроде всё в порядке. Но у меня вот повились сомнения, вдруг надо вызывать эти функции в обратном порядке. Я попробовал, окно так же появляется. Может, и так и так правильно?

Comment: Просто в одном случае вы позиционируете еще не видимое окно, а в другом - уже отображенное

Comment: Вообще-то `SetWindowPos` уже само включает в себя возможности `ShowWindow` через флаг `SWP_SHOWWINDOW`. Так что если вы все равно собираетесь делать `ShowWindow`, то можно сделать это еще в `SetWindowPos`.

Comment: @AnT Комментарий явно тянет на ответ

Comment: @tutankhamun `ShowWindow` мне необходима, т. к. мне надо показывать окно в первый раз либо развёрнутым, либо свёрнутым, либо восстановленным, в зависимости от настроек, которые читаются из файла настроек при старте.

Comment: @0Zerro, конечно, логичнее сначала выставить размер, а потом уже показать окно. Вы не видите разницы между перестановками потому что делаете обе операции в одном потоке, блокируя очередь сообщений. Отрисовка окна все равно произойдет позднее, когда запустится цикл обработки сообщений. К тому же, `SetWindowPos` можно по разному вызывать. Вобщем, без конкретного кода вопрос не имеет особого смысла.